Unity , панель перекрывает кнопки
у меня есть 3 сцены на каждой из них кнопка - допустим "продолжить". Я сделал плавный переход за счет анимации затухания(то есть в канвас добавлена панель, на которой висит анимация с переходом на следующую сцену). Ну так вот, при переходе на 2 сцену кнопка на ней не реагирует на нажатия(я думаю из за панели которая из черной становится прозрачной(то есть у меня на сценах по 2 панели) и она при том активна. Но я не имею понятия как сделать ее неактивной после анимации, или возможно я сделал неправильную механику.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Привет, попробуй написать код который после проигрования анимации будет удалять обьект object.Destroy
